# ERROR in sms sending

Tags: java, android, adt

THIS IS THE ERROR: 
The method `getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int)` in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (`new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, Intent, int`) error

here's the code from MainActivity.java:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.Telephony.Sms;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity

    {
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


          private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message) {
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0); // <--- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR

            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0); // <--- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR

            // ---when the SMS has been sent---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }

    });
}
```

}

---

I'm trying to make a Scheduled Auto sms sending, but i won't go far with this errors. PLEAS help.

Comment: You have a problem with your context being passed in as the error says. this is passing in onClickListener for some reason try to replace it with getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with your context being passed in as the error says. Replace this  with getApplicationContext()

```
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
```

Just replace those 2 lines !

Update :

I just tried that and it worked !

```
 package com.sm.mrecruit.activity;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.telephony.SmsManager;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity

 {
 Button btnSendSMS;
 EditText txtPhoneNo;
 EditText txtMessage;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {                
        String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
        if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
            sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


  private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(SENT), 0); // <--- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0); // <--- THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}

});
}
```

Thats it ! Try that !

Comment: It's gone now.Thanks. But now i have a new problem. It's not sending and doesn't show the toasts.

Comment: I think it would be better if you create a new question for that, you should close this question by accepting an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the same for both lines. The method `getBroadcast()` is expecting a context as it's first argument. When you call this method you are inside of an anonymous inner class, in this case an `onClickListener` class. When you provided the `this` keyword as the first argument, `this` refers to that `onClickListener` class. What you need instead is to grab the context of the application which you are currently in and provide that to the method. You can achieve that by changing the error causing lines like this.

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.getApplication(), 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainAcitivty.getApplication(), 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
```

Replace `this` with `MainActivity.getApplication()`.

Comment: Are the errors still on those same lines? If they are, check my updated answer.

Comment: it's gone now. But it's not sending.

Comment: You will probably want to post a new question for that. That way you can shorten the code down to just the areas that aren't working. Also, since this problem has been solved you should do your upvoting / answer accepting so this question wont be listed under the "unanswered" section.